# How hard is a known prefix hash preimage attack on SHA-2?

Tags: hash, attack, sha-2, preimage-resistance

Suppose the attacker knows $X, Z$ such that

$H(X || Y) = Z$

If `bit-length(Y) < 60` then a brute force attack is possible.

What if `bit-length(Z) = 256`  (such as in SHA-256), `bit-length(X) = 128`, or `bit-length(Y) = 256`? Are there any published paper with results/experiments with SHA-256/512 in full or reduced rounds? Are there specific known attack techniques?

Comment: I'm pretty confident there is nothing out there allowing a preimage attack of this kind on SHA-256 with full rounds.

Comment: Regarding the brute force attack, the bitcoin network could brute-force more than 60 bit quite fast (today - the question is 4 years old): Assuming [$5 \cdot 10^{18}$ hashes per second](https://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate), it would take the bitcoin network $\approx 0.23$ sec for a full search over $60$ bit.