# Is this implementation of Merkle Trees susceptible to second preimage attack?

Tags: merkle-damgaard, hash-tree, 2nd-preimage-resistance

I am trying to find a good implementation of Merkle Tree generation in Golang, and I need the tree to be resilient to [Second Preimage Attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81981/how-does-second-pre-image-attack-on-merkle-signature-scheme-work)

I have found [this standard implementation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/keybase/go-merkle-tree#pkg-overview) in the golang docs, but it looks to me like it is susceptible to Second Preimage Attacks, since it only uses 1 hashing algorithm for the leaf and interior nodes. Is this right?

Is so, is there a standard implementation of this available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does second pre-image attack on Merkle Signature Scheme work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81981/how-does-second-pre-image-attack-on-merkle-signature-scheme-work)

Comment: I've had read through that, and this makes me believe that the above implementation is not safe, however I am not 100% sure so wanted clarification on here

Comment: ok fair enough...

Comment: One cryptography hash function is enough as long as one puts level indicator into hashing, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/71313/18298)